# helm - how to iterate over map with complex values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In a helm chart want to iterate over a map that contains structured values.

I do know how to iterate over a map with simple string values. I also can iterate over an array that contains structured values (not shown here). But I did not manage to iterate over a map that contains structured values.

This is my directory structure containing 3 files:

```
templates/test.yaml
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
```

A simple file Chart.yaml (just for completing the showcase):

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "1.0"
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: foochart
version: 0.1.0
```

The file values.yaml with a map that contains simple string values (label) and one that contains structured values (label1):

```yaml
---
label:
  fook: foo
  bark: bar
label1:
  fook:
    name: foo
    value: foo1
  bark:
    name: bar
    value: bar2
```

This template test.yaml works:

```yaml
---
env:
  {{- range $k, $v := .Values.label }}
  - name: {{ $k }}
    value: {{ $v }}
  {{- end }}
```

But when I substitute `.Values.label` by `.Values.label1`, it produces no output.

This is my command for testing:

```bash
helm template foochart
```

Question: Is it possible to process a map with structured values? I would like to use something like `$v.name`. If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can in fact use syntax like `$v.name`, if you know that `$v` is a variable holding an object.

```yaml
env:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.label1 }}
  - name: {{ $k }}_{{ $v.name }}
    value: {{ $v.value }}
{{- end }}
```

If you know that it has exactly the syntax you want, there is an underdocumented `toYaml` function that takes an arbitrary object and returns it as unindented YAML.  In your example, each of the values has the form of an `env:` item, and if you know (or specify) that, you can write out literally:

```yaml
env:
{{- range .Values.label1 }}
  - {{ . | toYaml | indent 4 | trim }}
{{- else }}
  []
{{- end }}
```

(In this last example: I'm not assigning a variable, so `.` is temporarily reassigned to each value in the map, and the keys are lost; for each item, I convert it to YAML, indent it by 4 spaces, but then trim out leading and trailing whitespace; and if there are no values, I explicitly write out an empty list.)

It's usually easier to specify a format you want your values to be in, and work with that.  If you for some reason can't be sure which form you have, the template language includes [functions to test on a value's type](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/reflection.html), so in principle you can test:

```yaml
env:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.labelN }}
{{- if kindIs "string" $v }}
  - name: {{ $k }}
    value: {{ $v }}
{{- else }}
  - name: {{ $v.name }}
    value: {{ $v.value }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
  []
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think, I was on the right path. My example worked perfectly when I tried it at home with the newest release of helm. Maybe I have used an old version. I will check this on Monday.