# Helm 3, convert array of objects in values.yaml into comma separated string

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following structure in values.yaml file:

```
upstreams:
- service_name: service_a
  mapped_port: 1000
- service_name: service_b
  mapped_port: 1001
```

I want this to be rendered like this in my deployment.yaml template:

```
"service-upstreams": "service_a:1000, service_b:1001"
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Does the technique in [helm - how to iterate over map with complex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824694/helm-how-to-iterate-over-map-with-complex-values) help you get started?

Comment: I did try this:

```
upstreams:
- service_a:1000
- service_b:1001
```

and then:

```
        {{if .Values.upstreams -}}
          "service-upstreams": {{ join "," .Values.upstreams | quote }}
        {{- end }}
 
```

But all attempts to read from the object failed for me with various template engine errors. Can't find any good example of that elsewhere, seems like I need to dive deep golang templating syntax with helper functions while I wanted to quickly solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over the objects in the `upstreams` value and concatenate the values.

### Definition of upstream helper template

templates/_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "sample.upstreams" -}}
{{- if .Values.upstreams }}
{{- range .Values.upstreams }}{{(print .service_name ":" .mapped_port ) }},{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

### Using the template (in this example as a label)

templates/deployment.yaml

```
metadata:
  labels:
    {{- if .Values.upstreams }} 
    service-upstreams: {{- include "sample.upstreams" . | trimSuffix "," | quote }} 
    {{- end }}
```

I'm not trimming the comma in the template because `trimSuffix` does not accept curly brackets as part of an argument

I would refer to the answer David Maze linked and [range](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action) documentation