# How to loop through a complex nested map in Helm Charts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to associate users in a aws-auth config map using Helm. I'd like to loop through a nested map in our values file. My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
  mapUsers: |
  {{- range $username := .Values.users }}
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      userarn: {{ $username.adminArn }}
      username: {{ $username }}
  {{- end }}
```

And the values file is as follows:

```
users:
  username: user.name
    userArn: user/Arn
    adminArn: user/AdminArn
```

I'm not certain if this will solve my problem and would like some feedback.

Comment: Your values file seems like incorrect yaml. You should either have users as an array, like `users: { [username: "user.name", userArn: "user/Arn", adminArn: "user/AdminArn"]}` (comments cant set correct multiline yaml, but you'll get an idea)

Or you should have hashmap like `users: { user.name: { userArn: "user/Arn", adminArn: "user/AdminArn"}}`

Depending on structure you need you will get different answers

Comment: How would I access the values if I use a hashmap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [helm - how to iterate over map with complex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824694/helm-how-to-iterate-over-map-with-complex-values)

Answer (score 1):

After taking feedback from @Andrew, I was able to get this to work by first changing the structure of my values file to:

```
users:
  testuser:
    username: test.user
    userArn: testuser/arn
    adminArn: testuser/adminArn
```

I then was able to update my loop to:

```
  {{- range $k := .Values.users }}
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      userarn: {{ .adminArn }}
      username: {{ .username }}
  {{- end }}
```