Represent Golang Map Objects in k8s ConfigMap Using helm
I have a map variable in golang as my config:
MyConfig map[int64][]int64 `mapstructure:"my-config"`

I tried to define this config in my helm files as follows:
Config Map:
my-config: {{ .Values.config.myconfig }}

Values:
myconfig:
  1: [2]
  2: [1]

But it rendered as:
my-config: map[1:[2] 2:[1]]

I also changed my config structure as follows:
Application:
MyConfig []MyConfigItem `mapstructure:"my-config"`

MyConfigItem struct {
    FirstPart  int64   `mapstructure:"first-part"   validate:"required"`
    SecondPart []int64 `mapstructure:"second-part"  validate:"required"`
}

Config Map:
my-config: {{ .Values.config.myconfig }}

Values:
myConfig:
  - first-part: 1
    second-part: 
      - 2
  - first-part: 2
    second-part: 
      - 1

But it rendered as:
my-config: [map[first-part:1 second-part:[2]] map[first-part:2 second-part:[1]]] 


What is in between this Helm configuration and the Go code?  Are you trying to pass it through a config file, an environment variable, something else?  How do you run this in a non-container environment?  How are you trying to pass it through the Kubernetes layer?

I have found a solution for the second way. This is how I setup my config map file:
my-config: 
{{- range .Values.config.myConfig }}
  - {{ . | toYaml | indent 4 | trim }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
  []
{{- end }}

I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64830481/1626977
But applying this solution on the first mode did not result in a proper configuration. The rendered config was:
my-config:
  - "1":
    - 2
  - "2":
    - 2

The keys are string, but they should be integers.
I will search more to find out the proper solution for the first mode too; I will update the answer if I find any.
